# How do you debug a record triggered flow triggered by owner change?

Tags: visual-workflow

How does one debug an before save flow triggered by owner change?
I have a before save trigger that checks if the account owner has been changed and if so proceeds to do a second check then updates the record.

I think my logic is correct but the record is not getting updated and I don't know any other way to debug since running the flow in debug mode, the ownerid is greyed out.

The tier change path is working correctly but the owner change is not.

I am testing by changing the owner in a record where the target tier is top 5(as seen in decision element) but the update is not happening so I am guessing the path is not being taken at all.

Thanks!

See the attached screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]